# R: How to save plot of "find_droughts" function from "lfstat" package as an image using code?

Tags: r

When I try to save this particular plot as an image, I only get an empty white image file. With this same code I managed to save multiple other "normal" plots, but it just won't work for find_droughts function (maybe also for some others).

I can save the plot manually by clicking "Export" in the Viewer, but I have a lot of plots to save and I would really like to do it using code.

This code generates the plot I have in mind:

```
library(lfstat)

# random data
date<-seq(from=as.Date("2018-01-01"), to=as.Date("2018-12-31"), by="days")
flow<-c(runif(150, min=50, max=180),runif(95, min=25, max=50),runif(120, min=50, max=400))

# dataframe
flow.df<-data.frame(day(date),month(date),year(date),flow)
names(flow.df)<-c("day", "month", "year", "flow")
#dataframe to lfobj
lfobj <- createlfobj(flow.df,hyearstart = 1, baseflow = FALSE)
# lfobj to xts
flowunit(lfobj)<-"m^3/s"
xts<-as.xts(lfobj)

# find droughts
droughts<-find_droughts(xts, threshold=47, drop_minor = 0)

# Save plot as .png
savehere<-"C:/.../"
filename<-"myplot.png"
mypath <- file.path(paste(savehere,filename, sep = ""))
png(file=mypath)
plot(droughts)
dev.off()
```

I need help with the last step - "# Save plot as .png".

And if anybody knows a way to change title of this plot, names of axis labels and so on, this would also help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that the default plot from the 'find_droughts' function is an interactive plot based on dygraph package.

I can think of two ways to overcome your issue.

1. If you want to plot static png, you can define on the plot function the type of the plot, so it's not the default (interactive) anymore. Based on your code, it will be:

   ```
   # Save plot as .png
   savehere <- "C:/.../"
   filename <- "myplot.png"
   mypath <- file.path(paste(savehere,filename, sep = ""))
   png(file=mypath)
   plot(droughts, type='l') # by defining type 'l', it will provide a plot of xts object, which is static
   dev.off()
   ```
2. If you want to plot an interactive plot, you can do something as below:

   ```
   # Save plot as .html
   library(htmlwidgets) # for saving html files
   savehere <- "C:/.../"
   filename <- "myplot.html"
   mypath <- file.path(paste(savehere,filename, sep = ""))
   InteractivePlot <- plot(droughts)
   saveWidget(InteractivePlot , file=mypath)
   # the above function will generate the interactive plot as an html file, but also a folder, which you might want to delete, since it's not required for viewing the plot. For deleting this folder you can do the following
   foldername <- "myplot_files"
   mypath <- file.path(paste(savehere,foldername , sep = ""))
   unlink(mypath, recursive = T)
   ```

Hope this helps.